# Custom button in ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

On ActiveAdmin, I have a form like this:
Note that "My thingy" is not on the DB, but calculated with the data from an API.
[image]

I want to add a filter for this field. What I'd like is to send this `abc` text as a parameter to the same edit action in which I am.

[image]

My form looks like this:

```
form do |f|
  f.inputs "Details" do
    f.input :my_thingy,
      label: 'My thingy',
      as: :select,
      collection: my_thingys,
    f.input :my_thingy_filter, label: "Filter My thingy by..."
    f.button :filter
  end
  f.actions
end
```

What I'd like is for this button to redirect to the same page, with the value of `my_thingy_filter` as a parameter.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this using a `member_action`:

```
member_action :thingy_filter, method: :patch do
  redirect_to edit_thingy_path(resource, thingy_filter: params["thingy"]["thingy_filter"])
end
```

And `formaction` with the button:

```
form do |f|
  f.inputs "Details" do
    f.input :my_thingy,
      label: 'My thingy',
      as: :select,
      collection: my_thingys,
    f.input :my_thingy_filter, label: "Filter My thingy by..."
    f.button "Filter", formaction: "thingy_filter"
  end
  f.actions
end
```

Anyhow, this problem was better solved by adding [a better select](https://github.com/codevise/activeadmin-searchable_select)